# Create Downloadble link of app

Tags: android

can anyone tell me how could i create a down loadable link for my android app for users.
so that i can send them a mail. and as user click on that mail from mobile my app start installation. how could i do this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to enhance fredley's answer, if you run your own web server or have it hosted, you may need to ensure the mime type is set to the correct value, ie, "application/vnd.android.package-archive" as well as ensuring that the suffix is .apk . You can see an way of doing this at www.barcodebeasties.com/downloads (sorry for the blatant advert - but an example often speaks 1000 words).

Comment: can u explain this with an example Richard..and where should i set this type..plz explain a little more

Comment: That depends on where you are going to be hosting your application for downloading. Do you run a webserver or have an account on a webservice that allows you to have binary downloadable files?

Answer (score 2):

Just upload the apk to your website, and email them a link to the apk. When they download it, they will be able to install it, as long as they have enabled third party app installation on their device. You can also provide a market link as detailed [in the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you are distributing your app through the Android Market, use a link something like this:

```
market://search?q=pname:com.yourdomain.yourapp
```

Clicking on this will only work from an Android device.  It will launch the Market app and take the user to your app's listing.